# AddOrUpdate throws "A foreign key value cannot be inserted" with one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5

My application targets .NET 4.5 and uses EntityFramework 5.0, Sql Server Compact 4.0.

I'm trying to seed my database with some entities, but it keeps throwing:

"System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = FK_dbo.User_dbo.Account_AccountKey ]"

Here is a simplified version of my domain entities:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

internal class AccountMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.AccountKey);
        this.Property(e => e.AccountKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}


public class User
{
    public int UserKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public int AccountKey { get; set; }
}

internal class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.UserKey);
        this.Property(e => e.UserKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();


        this.HasRequired(e => e.Account)
            .WithMany(e => e.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountKey);
    }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();

        modelBuilder.LoadConfigurations();
    }

}
```

The connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TestDb.sdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And here is a sample application which shows the issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestContext>());
            using (var context = new TestContext())
                context.Database.Initialize(false);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
                using (var context = new TestContext())
                {
                    var account1 = new Account()
                    {
                        Name = "Account1"
                    };

                    var user1 = new User()
                    {
                        Name = "User1",
                        Account = account1
                    };

                    context.Accounts.AddOrUpdate(
                        e => e.Name,
                        account1
                    );

                    context.Users.AddOrUpdate(
                        e => e.Name,
                        user1
                    );

                    context.SaveChanges();

                    Console.WriteLine("\nChanges saved.");
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The Account class has a one to many relationship with User class. My seed method tries to initialize a default Account with a default User. One would think that is a common usage of the AddOrUpdate method, but it does not seem to work in this case. If I just add the same account twice, with no user, it works with no problems.

Does anyone can see what point I am missing?

Is there something wrong in this simple relationship?

Is the AddOrUpdate method designed to work in situations like this?

If not, what would be the correct approach to accomplish that kind of seeding?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on track:

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    // with 1:many we don't need to specify PK when seeding, EF will pick this up
    var accounts = new List<Account>
    {
        // new a list of type User for each account
        new Account() { Name = "Account1", Users = new List<User>() },
        new Account() { Name = "Account2", Users = new List<User>() }
    };
    accounts.ForEach(a => context.Accounts.AddOrUpdate(a));
    context.SaveChanges();

    var users = new List<User>
    {
        // set the account key for each User
        new User() { Name = "User1", AccountKey = 1 },
        new User() { Name = "User2", AccountKey = 1 },
        new User() { Name = "User3", AccountKey = 2 },
        new User() { Name = "User4", AccountKey = 2 }
    };
    users.ForEach(u => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u));
    context.SaveChanges();

    // add users to list of type user in an account
    accounts[0].Users.Add(users[0]);
    accounts[0].Users.Add(users[1]);
    accounts[1].Users.Add(users[2]);
    accounts[1].Users.Add(users[3]);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**EDIT**

You'd probably want to drop and recreate your database before doing this, because if you seeded your database several times and "add the same account twice, with no user", there will be a number of rows in the account table and none in the user table.

You could also add the following annotation to `User.Account`:

```
[ForeignKey("AccountKey")]
public Account Account { get; set; }
```

Also, what's the reason none of your navigation properties are virtual?

Comment: I'm not using attributes because I favor the configuration sintax over them, and the one you suggest should behave basically the same as the ".HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountKey)" in UserMap. My navigation properties are not virtual because I don't need/want to support lazy loading.

Comment: Fair enough, annotations don't look as pretty. I agree using Fluent API should have the same affect - you could always try using an annotation instead of Fluent API to see if your Fluent config is causing the problem. Did you get the same error when you tried to use the example I provided?

Comment: Your example won't work because you are denying the purpose of the AddOrUpdate method making it verify the entity existence by id (the default method when you don't specify the identifying property), which you don't have. In my example, your approach will create four accounts, two named "Account1" and other two named "Account2". Besides, you are assuming the created account keys (1, 2), but you can't do that because the seed may be used in a migration, on an existing database.

Comment: My example does work, I've used it myself. It works perfectly for first-time seeding of a database, which from the amount of information you give in your question appears to be what you're trying to do. My example won't create four accounts, do you see it inside a loop that will iterate twice? I added in an extra account for illustrative purposes. Notice how I said "this should get you on track", implying the answer should act as a basis to help you resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes, @MattSull, I agree with you: your example does work for a first-time seeding. However, if that was the case, the AddOrUpdate method wouldn't be needed, a simple Add would suffice. That's why I included a "loop" in my example, to express that the seed method would be running in a database already populated.

Comment: I agree .Add would suffice. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working with the following modifications:

```
var account1 = new Account()
{
    Name = "Account1"
};

var user1 = new User()
{
    Name = "User1",
    //Account = account1
};

account1.Users = new List<User>(new[]{user1});

context.Accounts.AddOrUpdate(
    e => e.Name,
    account1
);

context.SaveChanges();
```

However, I don't know why that works. I still think the first attempt makes sense and should work with no problems.